# New to .htaccess and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

I'm making a site where users can create subdomains with files, folders etc.
these sites go into a folder called websites so it will be

```
site.com/websites/subdomain.site.com
```

I only need to get `{REQUEST_URI}` at the end of the `RewriteRule` so that a user can go to
example, `subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg` and still their *subdomain* will be shown like `subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg` but the content will actually be on `site.com/websites/subdomain.site.com/images/etc/img.jpg`

Sorry for creating multiple questions, the docs is hard for me i'm totally new to this but im trying... please help with this :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%1/ [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .htaccess is quite close to what you want. You just need to use `$1` as well as shown:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%1/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

`%1` only refers to the domain matched in `RewriteCond`.
`$1` is required to refer the rest of the URL matched in `ReqwriteRule`.

**EDIT**: To exclude `www.` and `site.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(site\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%1/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: Thanks... is it possible to exclude www. from it?

Comment: I mean kill the wholde query if the user visits the main page www.site.com site.com or site.com/index.php? thanks for your help

Comment: @user1930593 You mean www.site.com should go to site.com and www.subdomain.site.com to subdomain.site.com in the address bar?

Comment: No i want www.site.com, site.com, www.site.com/login.php, www.site.com/register.php, etc... all to show the original content no rewriting unless there is (.*).site.com except www. hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Consider "subdomain" is a folder inside ur website then try this below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already subdomain.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for subdomain/, go to subdomain.website.com
RewriteRule ^subdomain/$ http://subdomain.site.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Sub-domain is not known. It will be created by the users.